# Slack formatting not properly working with MS Bot Framework message

Tags: c#, botframework, slack

I'm sending a message with a line break in it. [Slack documentation](https://api.slack.com/docs/message-formatting) suggests using `\n`, yet when i do this, it does not appear in Slack. It just shows a white space.

My code is quite straightforward and looks like this:

```
await context.PostAsync("You mentioned this subreddit: " + match.Value
                        + "\nSubreddit link: https://reddit.com/" + match.Value);
```

As you see there is a \n character, yet Slack just shows it in 1 line, like this:

`You mentioned this subreddit: r/slack Subreddit link: https://reddit.com/r/slack`

Is it a bug or am I missing something?

Comment: Does it show "r/" or "\n"? I wouldn't expect that output from `"You mentioned this subreddit: " + match.Value + "\nSubreddit link: https://reddit.com/" + match.Value`

Comment: 'match.Value' is in this case the string 'r/slack'. But the \n doesn't show up at all. It's just a white space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case somebody is struggling with this too, it turns out that the MS Bot Framework parses the messages to Markdown. So you have to use 2 newlines to create a breakline